# How can I chain dependency resolutions?

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection, ninject

As you can see, I've bound my IDbClassesDataContext. What I want to do is chain the next one, so that when IMovieRepository is resolved, it'll pass the resoloved IDbClassesDataContext.

```
    kernel.Bind(Of IDbClassesDataContext).To(Of DbClassesDataContext) _
        .WithConstructorArgument("connection", connectionString)

    kernel.Bind(Of IMovieRepository).To(Of MovieRepository)() _
        .WithConstructorArgument("dataContext", IDbClassesDataContext)
```

I've also tried this:

```
    kernel.Bind(Of IDbClassesDataContext).To(Of DbClassesDataContext) _
        .WithConstructorArgument("connection", connectionString)

    kernel.Bind(Of IMovieRepository).To(Of MovieRepository)() _
        .WithConstructorArgument("dataContext", _ 
         Function(context) context.Kernel.Get(Of DbClassesDataContext)())
```

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT:

For the record, if I pass in an initialized DbClassesDataContext, it works fine.

```
 kernel.Bind(Of IMovieRepository).To(Of MovieRepository)() _
            .WithConstructorArgument("dataContext", initializedObj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the title: *Dependency resolutions are chained automatically by Ninject, if matching bindings are available.*

If the dependency of `MovieRepository` is any `IDbClassesDataContext` you do not have to specifiy `WithConstructorArgument` explicitly. Ninject is able to resolve the dependency on `IDbClassesDataContext` automatically if it is already bound.

Just remove the `WithConstructorArgument` method on `IMovieRepository` binding and check that `MovieRepository` depends only on `IDbClassesDataContext`.

*To your code:*

In the first case I do not understand this line:

`.WithConstructorArgument("dataContext", IDbClassesDataContext)` - *Is this compilable?*

In the second case you are trying to get from kernel the instance of `DbClassesDataContext`, but the binding code is for its interface - `IDbClassesDataContext`. To make it work it should be:

```
kernel.Bind(Of IMovieRepository).To(Of MovieRepository)() _
        .WithConstructorArgument("dataContext", _ 
         Function(context) context.Kernel.Get(Of IDbClassesDataContext)())
```